# Combine Two Tables in Select (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

If I have two tables, like this for example:

Table 1 (products)

```
id
name
price
agentid
```

Table 2 (agent)

```
userid
name
email
```

How do I get a result set from products that include the agents name and email, meaning that `products.agentid = agent.userid`?

How do I join for example `SELECT WHERE price < 100`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edited to support price filter**

You can use the `INNER JOIN` clause to join those tables. It is done this way:

```
select p.id, p.name as ProductName, a.userid, a.name as AgentName
from products p
inner join agents a on a.userid = p.agentid
where p.price < 100
```

Another way to do this is by a `WHERE` clause:

```
select p.id, p.name as ProductName, a.userid, a.name as AgentName
from products p, agents a
where a.userid = p.agentid and p.price < 100
```

Note in the second case you are making a natural product of all rows from both tables and then filtering the result. In the first case you are directly filtering the result while joining in the same step. The DBMS will understand your intentions (regardless of the way you choose to solve this) and handle it in the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. And it works like a charm. Went for the first version :)

Comment: I recommend against the second format, for two reasons: (1) it's very easy to accidentally leave out the join criteria altogether, and wonder why you suddenly have a Cartesian product, and (2) the `INNER JOIN` format makes it much easier to separate join criteria from filter criteria, making the query easier to parse for others.

Comment: Totally agree. It is also much more easy to read and hence, quicklier to understand the first one than the second one

Answer (score 7):

This is a very rudimentary `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  products.name AS productname,
  price,
  agent.name AS agentname
  email
FROM 
  products
  INNER JOIN agent ON products.agentid = agent.userid
```

I recommend reviewing basic `JOIN` syntax and concepts. [Here's a link to Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx), though what you have above is pretty universal as standard SQL.

Note that the `INNER JOIN` here assumes every product has an associated `agentid` that isn't NULL.  If there are NULL `agentid` in `products`, use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead to return even the products with no agent.

Comment: I noticed you changed your answer from JOIN to INNER JOIN, can you very briefly explain why? And also help me on where to put in the WHERE clause...

Comment: @Jesper because I forgot for a second whether SQL Server interpreted a bare `JOIN` as an `INNER JOIN` rather than something else. (Other RDBMS' will implicitly do `INNER JOIN` for a bare `JOIN`).  The `INNER JOIN` only returns rows that have matching values from both tables.

Comment: The `INNER` keyword is optional for an inner join. I prefer to include it just to be explicit and make the code that much more self-documenting. In a complex query with both inner and outer joins, being explicit keeps all join types more visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.name productname, p.price, a.name as agent_name, a.email
from products p
inner join agent a on (a.userid = p.agentid)
```

Answer (score 1):

*This is my join for slightly larger tables in Prod.Hope it helps.*

```
SELECT TOP 1000 p.[id]
      ,p.[attributeId]
      ,p.[name] as PropertyName
      ,p.[description]
      ,p.[active],
      a.[appId],
      a.[activityId],
      a.[Name] as AttributeName 
  FROM [XYZ.Gamification.V2B13.Full].[dbo].[ADM_attributeProperty] p
  Inner join [XYZ.Gamification.V2B13.Full].[dbo].[ADM_activityAttribute] a
  on a.id=p.attributeId
  where a.appId=23098;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ProductName=p.[name]
, ProductPrice=p.price
, AgentName=a.[name]
, AgentEmail=a.email
from products p
inner join agent a on a.userid=p.agentid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use inner join (or don't have possibility to do it!) and would combine rows, you can use a cross join :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
```

or simply

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: This will bring a duplicate list from the first table.