# Merging columns from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in merging / add columns from a different table (tab2) into another table as per example in the last table below...using SELECT and also with the intention of CREATING another table to this effect.

Table name: Tab1

```
ID   Title  Firstname    Lastname      Telephone  ...10 other columns
1    Mr     Adam          Smith        001   
2    Mrs    Angela                     002  
3    Mr     Bill          Mowny        003 
4    Miss   Dame                       004   
5    Mr     Boya          Mala
```

Table name: Tab2

```
Cit_ID   DOB    Status Gender
1        12/84   S    Male
2        11/81   S    Female
3        13/80   M    Male
4        15/78   M    Female
5        13/67   M    Male
```

Intended Output table / name: Tab3

```
ID    Title  Firstname   Lastname      Telephone DOB   Status Gender ...10 other columns
1    Mr     Adam          Smith        001       12/84  S     Male
2    Mrs    Angela                     002       11/81  S    Female
3    Mr     Bill          Mowny        003       13/80  M    Male
4    Miss   Dame                       004       15/78  M    Female
5    Mr     Boya          Mala                   13/67  M    Male
```

I would like to create a new table for this purpose. Kindly help.

Comment: use `view` and `join` together, instead of creating another table and storing data again in it.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` and `INTO`.

Comment: Refer this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304984/combine-two-tables-in-select-sql-server-2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304984/combine-two-tables-in-select-sql-server-2008)

Comment: may outer join work for you

Answer (score 2):

> try this sql query

```
select * from Tab1,Tab2 where Tab1.Cit_ID=Tab2.ID
```

> Or u can Join table by using the following code

```
Select * from  Tab1 inner join Tab2 on Tab11.Cit_ID=Tab2.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as per sql server

```
SELECT * INTO tab3 FROM tab1 join tab2 on tab1.id = tab2.cit_id
```

I tried this on mysql in which `into` is not allowed

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS SELECT id FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.`cit_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one in mysql its working

its creating new table and inserting all values too

```
 create table new_table select * from Tab1 join  Tab2 on Tab1.ID=Tab2.Cit_ID;
```

NOTE : not tested in sql

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query

```
select ID,Title,Firstname,Lastname,Telephone, DOB,Status Gender,Column_10  from tab1,tab where tab1.cityid=1
```