# Join two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a solution to generate the result from tables Table1 and Table2. Please see below image for details

[image]

Table1.OrderID = Table2.OrderID

I'm not looking for a simple join query. In the output Table1 values not repeating.

Comment: That's a basic JOIN. Show us your query attempt!

Comment: Please post script and data as text, not images.

Comment: please do some research, this is not the sort of question you need to ask on here, you can find the answer with a quick search.

Comment: example one: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine Two Tables in Select (SQL Server 2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304984/combine-two-tables-in-select-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @Tanner We can join both tables, but the Table1 values will repeat in result. I'm looking for a solution for this.

Comment: guys he wants only the first iteration of table A and rest should come as blank even if they match

Comment: @ellickakudyrajeesh that's not how sql server returns results, that kind of formatting should be left to the front end application where you display the data.

Comment: Use Right outer join..

Comment: @Vinoth_S, right join - how come?

Comment: You can put sequence/serial numbers for each order id and then join it on both serial number and order id. That will do the job. This is still basic but good

Comment: @India.Rocket, if he shows us his query, I'll advice him to fix that in the presentation layer. It's not really an SQL thing.

Comment: @jarth that's why i didn't answer. just giving him the suggestion

Comment: @jarlh I have the query using inner join. But my issue is how we remove the duplicating Table1 values from result.

Comment: @jarlh I have got a solution using ROW_NUMBER(). Please see my answer below

Comment: @India.Rocket like your comment using  ROW_NUMBER() I got a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and finally I got a solution for what I'm exactly looking for

```
WITH MasterTable as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID ASC) AS SlNo,* FROM Table1),
DetailTable as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OrderID ORDER BY OrderID ASC) AS SlNo,* FROM Table2)

SELECT * FROM MasterTable A FULL JOIN DetailTable B
ON A.OrderID = B.OrderID AND A.SlNo=B.SlNo
ORDER BY B.OrderID
```

Comment: Nice buddy. You nailed it. Good :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select Table1.*, Table2.Items, Table2.Quantity -- List the columns you want. I've specified the table name to avoid ambiguous column errors, and * means all columns
from Table1
inner join Table2 -- This is a join (inner gets only the records that exist in both tables)
on Table1.OrderID = Table2.OrderID -- This is the join condition, you define which columns are the same between the tables
```

And for the blank bits, because you lack the sense to handle this in the display layer:

```
with CTE as
(
select Table1.*, 
       Table2.Items, 
       Table2.Quantity,
       row_number() over(partition by Table1.OrderID order by Items ) as rn
    from Table1
    inner join Table2 
    on Table1.OrderID = Table2.OrderID 
)

select case when rn = 1 then OrderID end as OrderID,
       case when rn = 1 then CustomerName end as CustomerName ,
       case when rn = 1 then CTE.Desc end as Desc,
       Items,
       Quantity
from CTE
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a join query. Please recheck my result. In the output Table1 values not repeating. It will be blank

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by using **ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY)**
code:

```
select 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tb1.orderid ORDER BY tb1.orderid) = 1 THEN tb1.orderid ELSE null END AS orderid,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tb1.custname ORDER BY tb1.orderid) = 1 THEN tb1.custname ELSE '' END AS custname,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tb1.Descp ORDER BY tb1.orderid) = 1 THEN tb1.Descp ELSE '' END AS Descp,
    tb2.item,tb2.quentity
    from tb1 inner join tb2 on tb1.orderid=tb2.orderid
```

Output :

```
orderid custname    Descp   item    quentity
   1    Ccustomer1  1item   Pen     1
   2    Ccustomer2  2item   Ball    2
                             Bat    1
   3    Ccustomer3  3item   Book    2
                            Box     1
                            Bag     1
                            Pen     2
```